# Padding +ve and -ve number in sprintf statement in c

Tags: c

I want to pad int 23 while printing as 023 and -23 as -023 in a single expression, is there any way to do it?
       eg.
       (not a perfect program just trying to explain what i want to do)

```
   int a=-23,b=23,c=-123,d=1;
   char arr[10];
   sprintf("arr,%d|%d|%d|%d",a,b,c,d);
```

o/p should be like

```
    arr = -023|023|-123|001
```

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: sprintf(arr,"%03d",a)
but it does not give me the exact answer for -ve number.

Comment: What does it give instead?

Comment: for positive number it gives 023 for negative it gives -23, but i want it as -023.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a precision in the printf format specifier to indicate the minimum number of digits, so if you want a minimum of 3 digits:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a = -23, b = 23, c = -123, d = 1, e = -2345;

    printf("|%.3d|%.3d|%.3d|%.3d|%.3d|\n", a, b, c, d, e);
    return 0;
}
```

Output: `|-023|023|-123|001|-2345|`

Answer (score 0):

- You can use below code.

  ```
  int main(void)
  {
    int a=-23,b=23,c=-123,d=1;
    char arr[10];
    printf("arr,%04d|%03d|%04d|%03d",a,b,c,d);
  }
  ```

Comment: For the record, this will only work for _this set_ of numbers. If the numbers change, then you will need different numbers.

Comment: when the variables are dynamic then? means when we dont know what values are coming in variables.

Comment: @user3121023, yeah, that worked. thanks a lot. But can you give a reference from where I can understand it properly?

Comment: what if i changed value from a = -23 to a = -2345?

Comment: sprintf(arr,"%0*d|%0*d|%0*d|%0*d",4+(a<0),a,4+(b<0),b,4+(c<0),c,4+(d<0),d);

Comment: So whts wrong with my answer?Means for in my ans also we can do it manually